# how to create tax zones

Tags: magento-2.1, tax

I set a tax zone for Poland. if I choose a country when ordering: Poland then correctly applies 23% tax.

If I choose a different country, then I do not add anything.

**How to set the same tax rate (23%) for all countries?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you create a zone for every allowed country manually or you can set up a CSV file and import the zones based on the following format:

```
"Code","Country","State","Zip/Post Code","Rate","Zip/Post is Range","Range From","Range To","default"
"pl-23","PL","*","","23.0000","","","",""
"at-23","AT","*","","23.0000","","","",""
"de-23","DE","*","","23.0000","","","",""
```

-- where Code must be a unique identifier for each rule and the country is to be seas 2-letter country code (i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)

You can import (and also export) tax rates from `System > Import/Export Tax Rates`. (Please note that the CSV export given in `Stores > Tax Zones and Rates` got a slightly different format and can not be used as a draft)